# Can i map control "b" (b pressed after control not together with it)?

Tags: key-bindings

I have this idea of binding `b` pressed after `control` (which would preserve original `C-b` behaviour to `Denite buffer` and `C f` to `Denite file_rec`.
But `nnoremap <silent> <C>f :Denite file_rec<CR>` doesn't work.

Oh, and I know all about leader key. I don't need any workaround.

Comment: I am not sure you can use Control as a standalone key. Sorry for bothering you with a workaround, but you can do something like `<C-B>b`. This way, when you press Control+b it will wait for the second 'b', if time goes out you'll get the original control+b function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is no, you can't. That is because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on its own is not mappable. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key works by substracting some value from the key code that is pressed with it, so for example <kbd>Esc</kbd> has same value and meaning in Vim as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>[</kbd>.

Comment: Not even in GUI versions?

Comment: Nope, there are hacks to remap it to capslock to ctrl and or ctrl to esc: https://github.com/mhinz/vim-galore#map-capslock-to-control . But nothing as free as you want. The closest I could find was the <C-b>b on the other comment.

Comment: I would need to think about it, but since I never use `C-b` and `C-f` I've decided to remap them for now. However on my main keyboard ergodox control pressed without other keys acts as ESC already, so maybe with right delays I can use `<Esc>b`. Interesting idea.

Answer (score 0):

While Vim (or the Terminal) do not support this, you can get this effect by using something like [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) (Mac) or [Autohotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (Windows).

You would use it to map a single `control` press to some key you are not using (like F12) and then use that for the mapping in Vim.

Comment: you can add `hammerspoon` to that list instead of Karabiner, because Karabiner Elements can't map control tap to escape on sierra.